# How To Show ViewController from CDVPlugin in Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, swift, cordova-plugins, xcode-storyboard

I have been struggling with this for a few days and cannot get it to work, nor find anyone else that seems to have figured this out. Hoping someone can help.

I have a simple ViewController with 2 views in a Storyboard in Swift that I am trying to open through a Cordova plugin (Android version works). I have gotten it to the point where it does not error and I see every line of code being hit, but I am still not seeing the ViewController show. The standalone version of the application works fine.

Here is the code for the plugin call:

```
import Foundation

@objc(SomePlugin) class SomePlugin : CDVPlugin {
    func show(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
        // step 1. take a storyboard variable
        var storyBoard:UIStoryboard? = nil
        storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        // step 2. un-box storyboard to sb variable
        if let sb = storyBoard {

            // step 3. create new window
            var window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

            // step 4. start view controller
            window.rootViewController = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as ViewController

            // step 5. make key window & visible
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

If anything else can be of help, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: Need to import your storyboard as

```
  <resource-file src="src/ios/MyStoryboard.storyboard"/>
```

Step 2: Import your framework as

```
  <framework src="src/ios/helloSwiftFrame.framework" custom="true"/>
```

Do the above two steps in plugin.xml

Step 3: Now to come to your .m file in your plugin

```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *yourViewController = [storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyStoryID"] ;
   [self.viewController presentViewController: yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

also don't forget to import your framework in .m file.

That's it done..!! Happy Coding