# How to show ViewController in Cordova in CDVPlugin using presentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, plugins

directly saying that this is not the same issue with [How To Show ViewController from CDVPlugin in Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326271/how-to-show-viewcontroller-from-cdvplugin-in-cordova)

because he had issue with Git Merges

I'm trying to show my ViewController with standard function, but this doesn't work because something missing, but I cannot understand what exactly. Standard call:

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated: YES completion:nil];
```

All imports:

```
#import "MyPlugin.h"
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
```

But after using presentViewController I get an error:

```
No visible @interface for 'MyPlugin' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'
```

Who knows what I need to add? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `presentViewController` is a method for `UIViewController`, my guess is `MyPlugin` is something else.

Comment: yes, in Cordova it's different. You can extend just Cordova main "class". In Native objectiveC it would be extended from UIViewController

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to make function:

```
- (UIViewController*) topMostController
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    return topController;
}
```

And use it like:

```
[[self topMostController] presentViewController:viewController animated: YES completion:nil];
```